# Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to memcached.domain.com:11211, Connection timed out (110) - Occurring Sometimes

Tags: php, memcached, ubuntu-14.04

Our memcached server is not responding sometimes. The following error message appears in our apache error logs about 20 times a day:

```
Memcache::connect(): Can't connect to memcached.domain.com:11211, Connection timed out (110)
```

Is there away to configure the timeout on memcached or to increase the number of requests memcached can handle?

Any advice on debugging this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: You can increase memcached connection limit in memcached config (-s flag). Are you using php-memcache 3.x maybe? I noticed similar problems with php7.1 + php-memcache 3.x when serwer load is high. Did you manage to figure out solution for this problem?